# Подмена значений cookie в браузере

Tags: php, безопасность, blowfish

вопрос конретно вот в чём : может ли пользователь какимто образом изменить  значения cookie в браузере , например заменить свои куки (логин и хэшированый пароль) крадеными и зайти на сайт под краденым аккаунтом ?? 
я сохраняю в cookie  логин и пароль(BlowFish) вот и думаю на сколько это безопасно

Comment: Ну, вообще возможно. Но это уже проблема пользователя, у которого украли куки - нечего вирусы качать. :)

Comment: тогда какой смысл хэшировать пароль ?

Comment: А зачем тогда ограждать частный дом забором, если его можно перелезть, а собаку застрелить? Я это к чему - дополнительная безопасность. Никто никогда не даст 100% защиты, но обезопасить надо как можно сильнее. А то что пользователь кому-то "подарит" свои куки, это целиком и полностью вина пользователя. Разработчик же со своей стороны сделал всё - в том числе и зашифровал пасс. :)

Answer (score 1):

> может ли пользователь какимто образом изменить значения cookie в браузере

может.

> на сколько это безопасно

это безопасно, если у вас нет способа вытянуть пароль другого пользователя. 
Установить в куках он может но откуда ему знать что нужно устанавливать?

темболее куки куками..но проверка скажем на 5-10 неверно введенных значениях в течении 5-10 минут никто не отменял....Делаете просто проверку что если пароль не верный не давать авторизовыватсья пользователю в течении 10 минут..и все никто не подберет пароль.Или просто капчу при авторизации, если есть куки то пользователь видит капчу, если куков нет то капчу и поля ввода логина и пароля.

Все конечно зависит от того сколько у вас других уязвимых скриптов.